# How can I force GetApps to open a link to my application?

Tags: android

I need to paste a link to my app in the GetApps store, and when I do this, the link opens in the browser and not in the GetApps app. I need to redirect the user to the app page to write a review, but there is very little documentation with GetApps and I don't know how to do this. Any ideas?

I tried to insert a link to the application in GetApps